# AutoComplete textboxes in C# with strange behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

In a Windows.Forms form in C# I have a combobox and a textbox. The textbox has AutoComplete turned on with an AutoCompleteCustomSource. The elements in AutoCompleteCustomSource depend on the selected value of the combobox. This means that I have to change the AutoComplete values every time the value of combobox changes. But doing this I have experienced some strange behaviour I don't like:

- text that was auto-completed keeps selected after leaving and reentering the textbox
- when leaving and reentering the textbox, the cursor will always be placed at the end of the text, even if I click somewhere between the characters
- using the backspace key causes the suggestbox to appear

I have the following short sample code which shows the described behaviour.
Try to enter "Must" for example in the textbox. "Mustang" should be suggested and appended after pressing TAB on the keyboard. Now select "Ford" from the combobox and reenter the textbox to see what I mean.

**Form2.Designer.cs**

```
partial class Form2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // comboBox1
        // 
        this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Audi",
        "Fiat",
        "Ford",
        "VW"});
        this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(87, 12);
        this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
        this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(193, 21);
        this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 15);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label1.Text = "Brand:";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 64);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(34, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label2.Text = "Type:";
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(87, 61);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(193, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 110);
        this.textBox2.Multiline = true;
        this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
        this.textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
        this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(268, 144);
        this.textBox2.TabIndex = 4;
        // 
        // Form2
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
        this.Name = "Form2";
        this.Text = "Form2";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private string[] types_audi = new string[] { "A4" };
    private string[] types_ford = new string[] { "Mustang", "Focus" };
    private string[] types_fiat = new string[] { "Punto", "500" };
    private string[] types_vw = new string[] { "Golf" };
    private List<string[]> types = new List<string[]>();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.types.Add(this.types_audi);
        this.types.Add(this.types_ford);
        this.types.Add(this.types_fiat);
        this.types.Add(this.types_vw);

        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_audi);
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_fiat);
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_ford);
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_vw);

        this.textBox1.Enter += new EventHandler(this.textBox1_Enter);
        this.textBox1.Leave += new EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);
        this.comboBox1.Select();
    }

    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox2.Clear();
    }

    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // reset AutoCompleteCustomSource
        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear();

        switch (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem as string)
        {
            case "Audi":
                this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_audi);
                break;
            case "Ford":
                this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_ford);
                break;
            case "Fiat":
                this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_fiat);
                break;
            case "VW":
                this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_vw);
                break;
            default:
                this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_audi);
                this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_fiat);
                this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_ford);
                this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_vw);
                break;
        }

        this.textBox2.Text = "Possible values: " + Environment.NewLine;

        foreach (var val in this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource)
        {
            this.textBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine + val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have autocompletemode set to suggest and AutoCompleteSource set to ListItems

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new string object to store the previously selected item from the combobox and clear the textBox1 in the textBox1_Enter method if the selected item in the combo is not the same as the previously selected item and then set the previously selected item to the current selected item.

It should be something like this:

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // reset AutoCompleteCustomSource
    var selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem as string;

    if (string.Compare(this.previouslySelectedItem, selectedItem) != 0)
    {
        this.textBox1.Clear();
        this.previouslySelectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear();

    switch (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem as string)
    {
        case "Audi":
            this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_audi);
            break;
        case "Ford":
            this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_ford);
            break;
        case "Fiat":
            this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_fiat);
            break;
        case "VW":
            this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_vw);
            break;
        default:
            this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_audi);
            this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_fiat);
            this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_ford);
            this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(this.types_vw);
            break;
    }

    this.textBox2.Text = "Possible values: " + Environment.NewLine;

    foreach (var val in this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource)
    {
        this.textBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine + val;
    }
}
```